# Is there any python method that can make valid URL from non-valid URL?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, url, urlencode

I try to Remove extra char from this URL(Please watch snapshot)

> [https://test.com/ABC]VR͜](https://test.com/ABC%5DVR%CD%9C)

[URL Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgJvO.png)

but I can't make it perfect URL format,
and I try this code

```
    import re

    p = re.compile(r'(?:\w*://)?(?:.*?\.)?(?:([a-zA-Z-1-9]*)\.)?([a-zA-Z-1-9]*\.[a-zA-Z]{1,}).*')

    domain = 'https://test.com/ABC]VR͜'

    print(p.match(domain))
```

[Code Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E7Bk.png)

but still, it gives output

> [https://test.com/ABC]\x1dV\x1dR͜\x1d](https://test.com/ABC%5D%5Cx1dV%5Cx1dR%CD%9C%5Cx1d)

where I need output like

> https://test.com/ABCVR

So, is there any build-in method in python to do that? or if need to make manually any way without regular expression? if no way without regular expression then how to do that with a regular expression?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid

This question shows which char need to remove but not show any method or programming way.

Comment: if your goal is to simply replace invalid characters, why not [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)